# How many pixels should an image should have for ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad

i'm working on a simple iPad native game, it is simple because i'm not using sprite kit or another frameworks to do so, i'm just using the animations and events to do this. My question is, what size or pixels should my images should have for iPad or iPad Retina? this is for beginning to make the art.

Comment: How should we know?  Are you asking what the screen size is for the iPad and iPad retina??  If so that is very easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your artwork should have as many pixels as possible. At least 4x larger than will actually be used on the device.

So if the artwork will be 50px square on a non-retina iPad and 100px square on a retina iPad, you should do the original artwork in at least 400px.

This way if you ever change your mind about the size of something, or if Apple makes the resolution higher in next week at WWDC or next year, you will not need to re-create all of your artwork.